Problema al cargar cuadro de mandos de Superset mediante Embedding
Estoy intentando cargar un cuadro de mandos que he hecho en Superset 3.0.1 a través de un Iframe (mediante el embedding). Ya he superado la parte de conseguir el "guest token" desde mi iframe y Superset me responde. Sin embargo en vez de presetar mi cuadro de mandos, me aparece un Unexpected error y en el detalle me dice Error: ORA-00920: operador relacional no válido.
He explorado la consulta que me hace desde mi iframe, y por algún motivo se añade un
 WHERE (string)

entre el "from" y el "grop by" de query. Desde Superset el cuadro funciona perfectamente, y si exploro la consulta no tiene ese where.
Sospecho que se está intentando crear un filtro, pero no se cómo controlar que no ocurra, mi consulta no usa filtros de ningún tipo.
He añadido todos los permisos al Rol Gamma.
Me pasa con todos los cuadros de mando.
Adjunto pantallazo de la consulta desde mi iframe.

Añado la consulta de la imagen como código. Si se quita el where o se sustituye el string por 1=1, la consulta funciona correctamente.
SELECT anon_1."NOMBRE_ASIGNATURA",
       anon_1."count"
FROM
  (SELECT "NOMBRE_ASIGNATURA" AS "NOMBRE_ASIGNATURA",
          COUNT(*) AS "count"
   FROM
     (SELECT a.nombre_asignatura,
             ta.nombre_tipo_asignatura,
             s.nombre_sexo
      from F_MATRICULA m
      inner join d_tipo_asignatura ta on ta.id_tipo_asignatura = m.id_tipo_asignatura
      inner join d_asignatura a on a.id_asignatura = m.id_asignatura
      inner join d_sexo s on s.id_sexo = m.id_Sexo) virtual_table
   WHERE (string)
   GROUP BY "NOMBRE_ASIGNATURA"
   ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) anon_1
WHERE ROWNUM <= 100;

Si os ha pasado algo parecido, os agradecería cualquier pista.

Hola Angel, bienvenido, para evitar que tu pregunta sea cerrada, y recibir votos negativos, te sugiero que la edites, y agregues el código como texto.

Sí ...where (string)... no tiene sentido.  String es un nombre reservado para un tipo y no es un valor.  Funciona si omite el WHERE?

Buenas, si quito el where, funciona. No se porqué aparece ese where cuando cargo el cuadro de mandos desde mi iframe. Si lo ejecuto desde superset, no aparece el where y funciona correctamente.
